# I don't understand why all the data gets printed in the arrange method correctly but does not get printed in the print method

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

In `tree` class there is a method called `arrange()`. When I print any node value within the `arrange()` method the value comes to be accurate, but when I use the method `print()` in `tree` class I get a `NullPointerException`. Please help!

```
public class Node {
    Node lnode;
    Node rnode;
    int data;

    public Node(String d) {
        data = Integer.parseInt(d);
        this.rnode = null;
        this.lnode = null;
    }
}

public class tree {

    public void arrange(String s[], int n, Node r) {
        Node root = new Node(s[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            r = root;
            if (Integer.parseInt(s[i]) > root.data && root.rnode == null) {
                root.rnode = new Node(s[i]);
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(s[i]) < root.data && root.lnode == null)
                root.lnode = new Node(s[i]);

            while (!(r.rnode == null) && (Integer.parseInt(s[i])) > r.data) {

                r = r.rnode;
                if (Integer.parseInt(s[i]) > r.data && r.rnode == null)
                    r.rnode = new Node(s[i]);
                else if (Integer.parseInt(s[i]) < r.data && r.lnode == null)
                    r.lnode = new Node(s[i]);
            }
            while (!(r.lnode == null) && (Integer.parseInt(s[i])) < r.data) {
                r = r.lnode;
                if (Integer.parseInt(s[i]) > r.data && r.rnode == null)
                    r.rnode = new Node(s[i]);
                else if (Integer.parseInt(s[i]) < r.data && r.lnode == null)
                    r.lnode = new Node(s[i]);

            }
        }
        System.out.println(root.rnode.data);
    }

    public void print(Node r) {
        System.out.println(r.rnode.data);
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
Node root;
int n;
System.out.println("Enter the number of elements you want to enter into the bst: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter the elements you want to enter into the bst: ");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String st[] = new String[n];
st = s.nextLine().split(" ");
root = new Node(st[0]);
tree t = new tree();
t.arrange(st, n, root);
t.print(root);
```

Comment: Node r passed into the print method is clearly null.

Comment: No the value of root is given in the main method

Comment: Where do you _call_ `print()`?

Comment: Well, seems like `node.rdata` is `null` then...

Comment: Believe the JVM.  You'll fix your problem QUICKLY if you believe when it tells you that reference is null.  This is an easy problem to solve with a debugger.  Set a breakpoint and inspect the call stack.

Comment: nope node.rdata is not null in my input

Comment: Please forget your input.  Put a breakpoint inside your print method and see why that node is null.

Comment: I don't know how to use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

The variable `root` is a reference to a `Node` object, which is passed by value to the `arrange` method. This means that every assignment you make to `r` inside `arrange` (that is, every time you use the `=` operator) will only last as long as you stay inside that method.

When your method returns, the value of `root` will be the same as before, thus triggering your `NullPointerException` when you try to access `r.rnode.data`.

Now that you know the problem, I would suggest you try to find a solution on your own. As the comments suggested, it is not that difficult!

Comment: How can access r.rnode.data outside the arrange method? Should i create a separate node while assigning the value (that is, every time you use the = operator) ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are aiming at. Should the `arrange` method modify the `r` parameter? In that case, you cannot use assignments, but you can still modify `r` member variables (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)). Should the `arrange` method calculate something? Then `return` the result.